# Performance Issue Calling SP and update Table within a cursor how can it be done correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am having a performance issue which I would like to read your opinion :

I am using a cursor that runs all Orders.
I have a table(Orders) which each order I would like to do a check  - by using a call to a sp (it returns a table)

I do an insert for the result into the table - > then I update another table.

so I have to insert then update 2 diff tables.
I must do the update in the cursor - I depend on that data.

Comment: I don't think anyone can help you based on this. Please provide details, data and query.

Comment: Please provide DDL, sample data and Actual executions plans

Comment: But why do you have to do it in cursor, can you make it like a three step process, If you having any calculations in cursor, do calculation first, then update the rest ... use temporary tables and finish it like that